# How to use Algolia with mongoose node js?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, algolia

I want to integrate Algolia with node.js mongoose but am currently stuck on what to do next.

I'm following the documentation on this package https://github.com/algolia/mongoolia but am currently lost on what to do next to query my database and make my search work.

These are my code so far:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
const mongoolia = require('mongoolia').default;
var algoliasearch = require('algoliasearch');

//meme schema
var meme = require('../app/model/meme');

const TagSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  tagarray: { type: String, required: true, algoliaIndex: true },
});

TagSchema.plugin(mongoolia, {
  appId: 'xx',
  apiKey: 'xx',
  indexName: 'test1'
})
```

I'd appreciate any help to move forward.

Answer (score 1):

The mongoolia plugin goal is to keep in sync your existing mongo database with an Algolia index. You'll always keep your mongo database as the source of truth for your data, but its content will also be replicated into Algolia and used for front-end search. Whenever an object will be added/edited/deleted in mongo, it will also be added/edited/deleted in Algolia.

Once you have this part in place (you can check in your Algolia dashboard UI to see if all your records are correctly there), you'll have to create (or replace) you front-end search.

The way Algolia works is by having searches made by your users on your website directly target the Algolia API instead of targeting your backend. Algolia also provides a JavaScript library called [InstantSearch](https://community.algolia.com/instantsearch.js/) that will allow you to build your UI using pre-defined widgets (think lego bricks). You will have one for the searchbar, another for the results, the pagination, the filters, etc. They will all be kept in sync, and all target your Algolia application?

In a nutshell mongoolia is the first part of the implementation (indexing data), you then need to use InstantSearch for the second part (searching the data).

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the search functionality working, you have to implement a function to utilize Algolia's default search method.

```
const client =algoliasearch('J6WRJSQ5IG','a43de33c567ad70d2a2edac8f8014176');
const index = client.initIndex('indexName');

// only query string
index.search('query string').then(({ hits }) => {
  console.log(hits);
});

// with params
index.search('query string', {
  attributesToRetrieve: ['firstname', 'lastname'],
  hitsPerPage: 50,
}).then(({ hits }) => {
  console.log(hits);
});
```

As stated in the offical [docs](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/api-methods/search/#examples)